# "in this section", "about this section" or "for this section"?

Tags: prepositions

In an online classroom, a teacher just finished a section and going to start next section

> Teacher: "Do you have any questions **in this section**?"
>
> Student: "No, I don't have any questions at the moment. Thanks!"

Should I say "in this section", "about this section" or "for this section" for this particular situation?

Ngram Viewer does not seem to be helpful for this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say “about this section” because you are asking them about a specific topic

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind explain a little bit about when other two are used?

Comment: “In this section” could be used to say “what do you want to learn in this section.” “In this section” can be used to ask students what they want to do in the particular section.

Comment: Thank you so much. In what situation "for this section" could be used?

Comment: I don’t really know how “for this section” is used. Sorry.